# Core file may or may not escape docker container, depending on the core pattern

Tags: kernel, docker, core-dump

I am a docker noob who recently ran into a problem. I quote a random  [pipermail from years ago](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/containers/2015-November/036347.html) that poses the question far more elegantly than I ever could:

> I noticed the following core_pattern behavior in my linux box while
>   running docker containers. I am not sure if it is bug, but it is
>   inconsistent and not documented.
>
> If the core_pattern is set on the host, the containers will observe
>   and use the pattern for dumping cores (there is no per cgroup
>   core_pattern). According to core(5) for setting core_pattern one can:
>
> 1. echo "/tmp/cores/core.%e.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
> 2. echo "|/bin/custom_core /tmp/cores/ %e %p " > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
>
> The former pattern evaluates the /tmp/cores path in the container's
>   filesystem namespace. Which means, the host does not see a core file
>   in /tmp/cores.
>
> However, the latter evaluates the /bin/custom_core path in the global
>   filesystem namespace. Moreover, if /bin/core decides to write the core
>   to a path (/tmp/cores in this case as shown by the arg to
>   custom_core), the path will be evaluated in the global filesystem
>   namespace as well.
>
> The latter behaviour is counter-intuitive and error-prone as the
>   container can fill up the core-file directory which it does not have
>   direct access to (which means the core is also not accessible for
>   debugging if someone only has access to the container).

The thread died before any kind of conclusion was reached.

Why is there this difference in behavior? Did it get resolved or is there any guidance about it now?

Comment: Related Stackoverflow question: [**“Piped” core pattern is not creating core dumps inside docker container**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986788/piped-core-pattern-is-not-creating-core-dumps-inside-docker-container)